# Get value of input in parent parent parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a table of several lines (the HTML is generated, I cannot modify it). In each row, there are 2 inputs (different column). When I modify the value of one of the inputs (with "qty" class name), I want to retrieve the value of the second input but I can't do it. Note that the number of lines is not fixed

My generated html and attempt

```js
jQuery('.qty').on('change', function() {
  console.log(jQuery(this).val());
  console.log($(this).closest("tr").children('.product_quantity').children('input').val());
})
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th class="product-quantity">Quantity 1</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="product-name">Name product 1</td>
      <td>$1,00</td>
      <td class="product-quantity">
        <input type="number" min="1" step="1" name="items[45955][quantity]" value="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="number" class="qty" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qté" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="" kl_vkbd_parsed="true">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="product-name">Name product 1</td>
      <td>$1,00</td>
      <td class="product-quantity">
        <input type="number" min="1" step="1" name="items[45955][quantity]" value="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="number" class="qty" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qté" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="" kl_vkbd_parsed="true">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
````

I tried to change closest by parents and many other test but I can't do it
Could you help me please ?

Comment: `closest('tr').find('input').eq(1)` to get the second one

Comment: Maybe wouldn't hurt to put a `id="product-xxxx"` on the `<tr>`? that way you can also send user down to that product, maybe create some `:target` style and simplify the closest target a bit by doing:  `closest('[id^=”product-”]').find(...)`

Comment: Note that the 2nd input is not in any way a "parent" of the first input (based on title of parent-parent-parent)

Comment: Note that `$(".product_quantity")` will **not** find `<td class="product-quantity">`  `"_" !== "-"` - fix the typo (change to `class='product_quantity'` in both rows) and your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to get the Action Value when you change the quantity value

Try this

```
$('.product-quantity input').on('keyup', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).parent('td').next('td').find('div input').val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".product-quantity input").val();
```